# Crashlytics error message for iOS Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics

I'm getting a transient error, `Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException` reported through Crashlytics (and observable while testing in simulator) that I can't for the life of me work out. It appears to be related to CoreFoundation:

```
-[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]
```

The main thread error message is:

```
Not possible to remove variable: 4: 0x28049ceb0:UISV-fill-proportionally.posErrorMarker{id: 5600} colIndex:6 from engine <NSISEngine: 0x14de1b8b0>{ delegate:0x14e86c0f0 EngineVars: 0: objective{id: 437} rowIndex:0 2: 0x28049d090:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 5598} colIndex:31 3: 0x28049cd20:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 5599} colIndex:3 4: 0x28049ceb0:UISV-fill-proportionally.posErrorMarker{id: 5600} colIndex:6 5: 0x28049ceb0:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 5601} colIndex:5 6: 0x28049cb90:UISV-fill-proportionally.posErrorMarker{id: 5606} rowIndex:26 7: <orphaned without delegate (bug!):0x283289280>{id: 2108} colIndex:0 8: 0x28049cb90:UISV-fill-proportionally.negError{id: 5607} colIndex:30 9: 0x28049ca50:UISV-spacing.marker{id: 5608} colIndex:29 10: GADBannerView:0x14ef33200.Height{id: 5238} rowIndex:1073741826 11: 0x280415ae0.marker{id: 5237} colIndex:1073741827 12: GADBannerView:0x14ef33200.Width{id: 5298} rowIndex:3 13: 0x28036c2a0.posErrorMarker{id: 5322} rowIndex:32 14: 0x28036c2a0.negError{id: 5323} colIndex:11 15: 0x28036e4c0.posErrorMarker{id: 5324} rowIndex:1073741827 16: 0x28036e4c0.negError{id: 5325} colIndex:1073741829 17: MarqueeLabel.MarqueeLabel:0x14ef1cc90.Height{id: 5240} rowIndex:1073741828 18: 0x280416b70.marker{id: 5239} colIndex:1073741828 19: MarqueeLabel.MarqueeLabel:0x14ef1cc90.Width{id: 5249} rowIndex:10 20: 0x28036d7a0.posErrorMarker{id: 5326} rowIndex:50 21: 0x28036d7a0.negError{id: 5327} colIndex:8 22: 0x28036c0c0.posErrorMarker{id: 5328} colIndex:1073741830 23: 0x28036c0c0.negError{id: 5329} rowIndex:1073741829 24: UILabel:0x14ef38c30.Height{id: 5242} rowIndex:1073741830 25: 0x280416850.marker{id: 5241} colIndex:1073741831 26: UILabel:0x14ef38c30.Width{id: 5259} rowIndex:12 27: 0x28036fea0.posErrorMarker{id: 5330} rowIndex:6 28: 0x28036fea0.negError{id: 5331} colIndex:13 29: 0x28036efa0.posErrorMarker{id: 5332} colIndex:1073741834 30: 0x28036efa0.negError{id: 5333} rowIndex:1073741831 31: UILabel:0x14ef38

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19847586c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1ad490c50 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x19837b000 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource addManagedSourceForIdentifier:user:]
3  Foundation                     0x199763728 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73dca0 _engineVar_rawRemove
5  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73ee1c -[NSISEngine removeConstraintWithMarker:]
6  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad756054 -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x19b286bc8 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
8  CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73c51c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
9  UIKitCore                      0x19b286ad8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x19b286e28 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
11 UIKitCore                      0x19b286d30 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
12 CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73c51c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x19b286ad8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
14 UIKitCore                      0x19b286e28 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
15 UIKitCore                      0x19b286d30 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
16 CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73c51c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
17 UIKitCore                      0x19b286ad8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
18 UIKitCore                      0x19b286e28 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2
19 UIKitCore                      0x19b286d30 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke
20 CoreAutoLayout                 0x1ad73c51c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x19b286ad8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
22 UIKitCore                      0x19b3622fc __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke
23 UIKitCore                      0x19b362210 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]
24 UIKitCore                      0x19b371574 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
25 UIKitCore                      0x19a74777c __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2
26 UIKitCore                      0x19b36a638 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]
27 UIKitCore                      0x19a747168 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke
28 UIKitCore                      0x19b36fed4 +[UIView _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:forScene:]
29 UIKitCore                      0x19a746b90 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x19a736358 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2
31 UIKitCore                      0x19a87795c +[UIInputResponderController _pinInputViewsForInputResponderController:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x19a7362d0 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.663
33 UIKitCore                      0x19b36a314 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:]
34 UIKitCore                      0x19a736108 _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition
35 UIKitCore                      0x19a6320e8 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
36 UIKitCore                      0x19a646afc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
37 UIKitCore                      0x19a647f88 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
38 UIKitCore                      0x19a629a18 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
39 UIKitCore                      0x19b377ec4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
40 QuartzCore                     0x19b892644 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
41 QuartzCore                     0x19b892b18 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
42 QuartzCore                     0x19b8a730c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
43 QuartzCore                     0x19b7ec640 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
44 QuartzCore                     0x19b817b08 CA::Transaction::commit()
45 UIKitCore                      0x19ae5dbf4 _afterCACommitHandler
46 CoreFoundation                 0x1983f0358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
47 CoreFoundation                 0x1983ea5c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
48 CoreFoundation                 0x1983eab74 __CFRunLoopRun
49 CoreFoundation                 0x1983ea21c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
50 GraphicsServices               0x1affb6784 GSEventRunModal
51 UIKitCore                      0x19ae2aee8 -[UIApplication _run]
52 UIKitCore                      0x19ae3075c UIApplicationMain
53 BTC Markets Ticker             0x102e1180c main + 22 (AppDelegate.swift:22)
54 libdyld.dylib                  0x1980aa6b0 start
```

The app is written in Swift using Xcode 12.4
The UI is created using the storyboard editor.
Has anyone come across anything similar before? This is occurring across multiple device types and app versions.

Comment: Have you found a solution so far? I am struggling with the same problem :(